# Find similarity between column of an id in r/python

Tags: python, r

The data is as follows:

```
id <- c(1,1,2,1,3,2)
address <- c("ABC Ret1","ABC","NY AB1","XYZ","DEL1","NY AB")
similar_address <- data.frame(id,address)
```

I want to find similar address of each id and make a new data.frame as below

[image]

Preferred is cosine similarity is used to find similarity among address

Comment: This post should help. Answer of JanLauGe
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49916981/using-cosine-similarity-in-string-vector-to-filter-out-similar-strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using function sim.strings from package qlcMatrix:

```
get_count_of_similar_strings = function(x){
  issim=(sum(sim.strings(x)>=.5) - length(x))/1
  isnotsim=length(x)-issim
  c(issim,isnotsim)
}

out = by(similar_address$address
,similar_address$id
,get_count_of_similar_strings
,simplify = T)    

data.frame(id=unique(similar_address$id),t(sapply(out,I)))
```

Comment: library(qlcMatrix)
id <- c(1,1,2,1,3,2,1,1)
address <- c("ABC Ret1","ABC","NY AB1","XYZ","DEL1","NY AB","ABC Ret","ABC")
similar_address <- data.frame(id,address)  ;;; Giving weird result with this data frame